# Determine the values of $a$ and $b$ where the function has inflection points $(x^2 + ax+b)(e^x)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

This is what I have so far:
I made the second derivative 
$$f''(x) = 2 e^x + 2 a e^x + b e^x + 4 e^x x + a e^x x + e^x x^2$$

and isolate the $x$:

$$x = \frac{1}{2}\biggl(\pm\sqrt{a^2 - 4 b + 8} - a - 4\biggr)$$

I guess I have to replace the $x$ in the second derivative so I could isolate $a$ or $b$.

But seems to me like a very long procedure and I'm not sure if there is a simpler solution.

Comment: So far so good.  Now, you have inflection points if $\sqrt{a^2 - 4b + 8}$ is real.  or Or $a^2 -4b + 8 \ge 0.$  However, If $a^2 -4b + 8 = 0$ then  $f''(x)$ does not change sign when $x$ crosses the root.  $a^2 -4b + 8 > 0.$

Comment: @DougM May I ask why if the root is 0 then f''(x) doesnt change sign? What's left in the fraction doesn't matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your computation we have that
$$f''(x) = e^x [x^2 + (a + 4) x + (2a + b + 2)].$$
You've found the solutions to $f''(x) = 0$, but we're actually asked for different information, namely, conditions on $a, b$ for which this equation has (real) solutions.

**Hint** Implicit in your work is the observation that any solution of $f''(x) = 0$ must be a root of the quadratic factor, $x^2 + (a + 4) x + (2a + b + 2)$. On the other hand, a quadratic polynomial $A x^2 + B x + C$ has real roots iff its discriminant, $$\Delta := B^2 - 4 A C ,$$ is nonnegative.